# Magento 2 - Get multi-store addresses REST API

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

I need to fetch the stores addresses using REST API.

We already have **storeConfigs** but this doesn't return the addresses.

```
GET  /V1/store/storeConfigs
```

[image]

How can we get the address mentioned in the Store Information tab. Also the Address is Website scoped but I need Store View based.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For your requirement then you need to build a Rest API yourself.**

**API points like:**

***webapi.xml Code***

```
 <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
    <route method="POST" url="/V1/devamitbera-systemconfig/systemconfig/">
        <service class="Devamitbera\Systemconfig\Api\SystemconfigManagementInterface" method="getSystemconfig"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
    <!-- getting all store detail -->
    <route method="GET" url="/V1/devamitbera-systemconfig/systemconfiglist">
        <service class="Devamitbera\Systemconfig\Api\SystemconfigListManagementInterface" method="getSystemconfig"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
</routes>
```

***Interface Class for getting Single store view.***

> ```
> Devamitbera\Systemconfig\Api\SystemconfigManagementInterface
> ```

**And code**

```
    <?php

    namespace Devamitbera\Systemconfig\Api;

    interface SystemconfigManagementInterface
    {

        /**
         * GET for getSystemconfig api
         * @param string $storeCode
         * @param string $path
         * @return string[]
         */
        public function getSystemconfig($storeCode =null );
    }
```

***Interface Class for getting all store view***:

> `Devamitbera\Systemconfig\Api\SystemconfigListManagementInterface`

**And code**

```
<?php
namespace Devamitbera\Systemconfig\Api;

interface SystemconfigListManagementInterface
{

    /**
     * GET for getSystemconfig api
     * @return string[]
     */
    public function getSystemconfig();
}
```

***Model Class for the interface class SystemconfigManagement:***

> `Devamitbera\Systemconfig\Model\SystemconfigManagement`

**Code:**

```
<?php

namespace Devamitbera\Systemconfig\Model;

class SystemconfigManagement implements \Devamitbera\Systemconfig\Api\SystemconfigManagementInterface
{


/**
 * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
 */
private $storeManager;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
 */
private $scopeConfig;

protected $configPaths = [
        'general/store_information/name',
        'general/store_information/phone',
        'general/store_information/hours',
        'general/store_information/country_id',
        'general/store_information/region_id',
        'general/store_information/postcode',
        'general/store_information/city',
        'general/store_information/street_line1',   
        'general/store_information/street_line2',
        'general/store_information/merchant_vat_number'                 
];

public function __construct(
 \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
 \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager 
 )
 {
     $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
     $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
}
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getSystemconfig($storeCode = null)
{

   if($storeCode === null){
       $storeCode = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getCode();
   }
   $storeConfigFinaData = [];

   foreach ($this->configPaths as $configPath) {
       $storeConfigFinaData[][$configPath] = $this->scopeConfig
               ->getValue(
                       $configPath,
                       \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORES,
                       $storeCode
                       );
   }

   return $storeConfigFinaData;
}

}
```

**Model Class for the interface class SystemconfigListManagementInterface:**

> `Devamitbera\Systemconfig\Model\SystemconfigListManagement`

**Code:**

```
<?php

namespace Devamitbera\Systemconfig\Model;

class SystemconfigListManagement implements \Devamitbera\Systemconfig\Api\SystemconfigListManagementInterface 
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\ResourceModel\Store\CollectionFactory
     */
    private $storeCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    private $storeManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    private $scopeConfig;
    protected $configPaths = [
        'general/store_information/name',
        'general/store_information/phone',
        'general/store_information/hours',
        'general/store_information/country_id',
        'general/store_information/region_id',
        'general/store_information/postcode',
        'general/store_information/city',
        'general/store_information/street_line1',
        'general/store_information/street_line2',
        'general/store_information/merchant_vat_number'
    ];

    public function __construct(
            \Magento\Store\Model\ResourceModel\Store\CollectionFactory $storeCollectionFactory,
            \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
            \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    ) {
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->storeCollectionFactory = $storeCollectionFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getSystemconfig() {


        $storeConfigs = [];
        $storeCollection = $this->storeCollectionFactory->create();
        foreach ($storeCollection->load() as $item) {
            $storeConfigs[] = $this->StoreInfomation($item);
        }

        return $storeConfigs;
    }

    private function StoreInfomation($store) {
        $storeConfigFinaData = [];
        $storeConfigFinaData['store_id'] = $store->getId();
        $storeConfigFinaData['store_code'] = $store->getCode(); 
        $storeConfigFinaData['website_id'] = $store->getWebsiteId(); 
        foreach ($this->configPaths as $configPath) {
            $storeConfigFinaData[$configPath] = $this->scopeConfig
                    ->getValue(
                    $configPath,
                    \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORES,
                    $store->getCode()
            );

        }

        return $storeConfigFinaData;
    }

}
```

**di.xml**

### TEST SAMPLE:

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "http://127.0.0.1/magento23dev/rest/V1/devamitbera-systemconfig/systemconfig/",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\"storeCode\": \"default\"}",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Authorization: Bearer gv5dgldyscnzpa8sveg1xfct9frnwy0q",
    "Content-Type: application/json",
    "Postman-Token: ff714339-e830-4347-8266-e458c58102d9",
    "cache-control: no-cache"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

This method support one parameter:

```
1.$storeCode : Store code
```

### All store Information API Test Sample:

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "http://127.0.0.1/magento23dev/rest/V1/devamitbera-systemconfig/systemconfiglist",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Authorization: Bearer gv5dgldyscnzpa8sveg1xfct9frnwy0q",
    "Content-Type: application/json",
    "Postman-Token: d9b495e5-3bc7-4e96-a723-3931b96b70ba",
    "cache-control: no-cache"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Amit. What is $path here : $storeConfigFinaData[][$path] Did you miss anything in the Model function ? How can I fetch the all stores because this seems to fetch only by storeCode.

Comment: OOPS ,typo mistake :) I have edited this answer

Comment: For fetching all store data at the single request you need to do some code

Comment: @amit.   => from where we get this token : gv5dgldyscnzpa8sveg1xfct9frnwy0q

Comment: I used integration token https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-token.html

Comment: how to update product based on store code in the model file?